# Shapefile and Raster with same CRS but NO output when clipping

Tags: r, crop, raster, mask, shapefile

Problem: Plot is empty, no results when clipping raster with shapefile.

I am using a shapefile with original EPSG4326 projection and a MODIS product with original sinusoidal projection. I converted both to the same projection (DesiredCRS) as you can see in the script, however when making a clip of the raster I don't get any results.

```
library(terra)
library(sf) 
library(sp) 
library(raster)

# Inputs
HDFfile <- "ModisProductsOriginal/MCD18A1.A2001001.h15v05.061.2020097222704.hdf"
Shapefile <- "Shapefile/Outline_5/Portugal_Outline_5_CAOP2019.shp"
DesiredCRS <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

# Feature
Shp <- st_read(Shapefile)
Terceira <- Shp[Shp$DI == '43',1]
Terceira <- st_transform(Terceira, DesiredCRS)
plot(Terceira, axes=TRUE)
```

Terceira's plot:
[Plot Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epUkL.png)

```
# Modis data
SDSs <- sds(HDFfile)
SDS8 <- SDSs[8]
SDS8_template <- rast(ncol=1200, nrow=1200, xmin=-34, xmax=-24, ymin=36, ymax=41, crs=DesiredCRS)
SDS8_reprojected <- project(SDS8, SDS8_template) # Reproject changes pixels?
SDS8_raster <- raster(SDS8_reprojected)
plot(SDS8_raster)
```

SDS8_raster's plot: [Plot Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMoAb.png)

```
# Clip
Clip.step1 <- crop(SDS8_raster, extent(Terceira))
Clip <- mask(Clip.step1, Terceira)
plot(Clip)
```

Clip.step1's plot: [Plot Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAyXT.png)

Clip's plot: [Plot Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjJfb.png)

All images show axes with the same projection. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong... Am I correctly defining the CRS and the extent?

**Updated:**

Panoply view of original shapefile and original HDF product:
[Panoply Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xde1q.png)

Plot of the two datasets together by Hijmans: [Plot Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ1zL.png)

Comment: You might put `library(terra)` and `library(sf)` at the top. What are the dims of SDS8, or should we take it they are the same as SDS8_template? Kinda scratching my head over the ?terra::project template stuff..

Comment: Terceira's x axis are + and SDS8 are -, albeit with the same numbers generally.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, libraries added.
dim(SDS8) is 1200, 1200, 1.
SDS8 is a SpatRaster, I used SDS8_template and SDS8_reprojected to have a better control over the raster creation, however other methods are welcome.

Comment: Yes, Terceira's x axis is positive, but you have W (West), shouldn't it be considered as negative by R?

Comment: Yes, west of prime is negative. Well, I'm guessing the representation doesn't matter so much, each of those libs have a plot method and which is used depends on the signature of the object plotted. What does Clip.step1 plot look like?

Comment: Added Clip.step1 plot to the question.

Comment: I think if you took an extent south of Terceira, you'd find you're doing this just fine. As you get to Clip.step1 you have two areas that are just touching with overlap of perhaps 1-2 pixels, and final mask says there's nothing to be found given the prior restrictions imposed (or the values you've used in mask or inverse=TRUE). So suggesting play around with mask and a different extent where you know there will be some overlap.

Comment: It looks a bit like the south of Terceira, however I don't understand were the gray pixels came from (left of coloured pixels).

Comment: I can only judge by the legend but values below 300 perhaps?  Since your final head scratch is that very small territory, perhaps get the xmin ymax of the bbox right there and see what values are present, or perhaps simpler, str(Clip.step1).

Comment: Terceira extent: -27.37945, -27.04121, 38.63899, 38.80343
SDS8_reprojected extent:-34, -24, 36, 41
Terceira is inside SDS8_reprojected so I don't think this is the real problem here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is but tricky to debug because you mix different packages, and you do not `show(object)`. Anyway, here is a terra approach, showing where it would be useful to see the objects metadata; and a plot that shows the raster and vector data together.

```
library(terra)
HDFfile <- "MCD18A1.A2001001.h15v05.061.2020097222704.hdf"
Shapefile <- "Portugal_Outline_5_CAOP2019.shp"
DesiredCRS <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

Shp <- vect(Shapefile)
Terceira <- Shp[Shp$DI == '43',1]

SDSs <- sds(HDFfile)
SDS8 <- SDSs[8]
```

Start by projecting the vector data to the original raster data.

```
TercSin <- project(Terceira, crs(SDS8))
plot(SDS8, 1)
lines(TercSin)
```

As you saw, that does not work. The reason is  that GDAL/PROJ reads from file or assumes the wrong ellipsoid

```
cat(substr(crs(SDS8),1,230), "\n")
#PROJCRS["unnamed",
#    BASEGEOGCRS["Unknown datum based upon the Clarke 1866 ellipsoid",
#        DATUM["Not specified (based on Clarke 1866 spheroid)",
#            ELLIPSOID["Clarke 1866",6378206.4,294.978698213898,
```

Or like this

```
describe("HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:\"MCD18A1.A2001001.h15v05.061.2020097222704.hdf\":MODISRAD:GMT_1200_DSR")[1:8]

#[1] "Driver: HDF4Image/HDF4 Dataset"                                         
#[2] "Files: MCD18A1.A2001001.h15v05.061.2020097222704.hdf"                   
#[3] "Size is 1200, 1200"                                                     
#[4] "Coordinate System is:"                                                  
#[5] "PROJCRS[\"unnamed\","                                                   
#[6] "    BASEGEOGCRS[\"Unknown datum based upon the Clarke 1866 ellipsoid\","
#[7] "        DATUM[\"Not specified (based on Clarke 1866 spheroid)\","       
#[8] "            ELLIPSOID[\"Clarke 1866\",6378206.4,294.978698213898,"
```

As you point out (and see [here](https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/modis-sinusoidal/)), MODIS (or at least some products) uses

```
modcrs <- "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m"
```

So let's try that

```
TercSin <- project(Terceira, modcrs)
plot(SDS8, 1)
lines(TercSin)
```

That looks OK. So we need to do

```
crs(SDS8) <- modcrs
```

and continue

```
Terceira <- project(Terceira, DesiredCRS)
Terceira

SDS8_template <- rast(ncol=1200, nrow=1200, xmin=-34, xmax=-24, ymin=36, ymax=41, crs=DesiredCRS)
SDS8_reprojected <- project(SDS8, SDS8_template) 
SDS8_reprojected

# Again plot the two datasets together
plot(SDS8_reprojected)
lines(Terceira)

Clip.step1 <- crop(SDS8_reprojected, Terceira)
Clip <- mask(Clip.step1, Terceira)
Clip

plot(Clip)
lines(Terceira)
```

[image]

Comment: This certainly simplifies the debugging, and given both the flux and rapid development of things `r-geospatial`, perhaps here/now should point to links to discussions of aspirations/accomplishments so that complex library calls might be replaced with simpler approaches henceforth. And I'm relieved in previously thinking, Hijmans will come and guide us out of our present dilemma.

Comment: Thanks for this approach, the plot of the two datasets together shows that the shapefile (Terceira) is displaced to the south in relation to the raster (SDS8_reprojected). I suspected that this could be the problem, however when opening the shapefile and HDF in Panoply this displacement does not exist, so I doubt that the problem is from the files. I will add the images to the question.

Comment: Can you share the HDF file? Also, I would start by projecting the vector data to the original raster data to, perhaps,  get to the root of the problem (see edits) .

Comment: I will share the HDF and shapefile on the top of the question. Changing the shapefile projection to the same as the raster gives me the same wrong displacement as before... What would lead me to think that the problem is with the original files if it weren't for Panoply, could there be a loss of information when extracting the SDS from the original file?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help! I added this line before TercSin: crs(SDS8) <- crs("+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs"). I had to remind R of the right CRS of the MODIS product. "Remind R", because when I checked SDS8 before your help I got always the right crs coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +units=m +no_defs

Comment: Thanks, I have used that to expand my answer